# regex ${something}

Tags: c++, regex, curly-braces, dollar-sign

How do I use regex to get what is inside of a ${} enclosed value such as:

```
Dont care about this. ${This is the thing I want regex to return} Not this either.
```

Should return:

```
This is the thing I want regex to return
```

I've tried \${ }$ 
the best I got messing around on regex101.com
I'll be honest I have no Idea what I'm doing as far as regex goes

using on c++ but would also (if possible) like to use in geany text editor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest `\${[^}]*}`. Note that `$` have special meaning in regular expressions and need to be escaped with a `\` to be read literary.

I use `[^}]*` instead of `.*` between the braces to avoid making a long match including the entire value of:

```
${Another} match, more then one ${on the same line}
```

`[^}]` means anything but `}`

Answer (score 1):

What you want is matching the starting `${` and the ending `}` with any amount of characters in between: `\$\{.*\}`. The special part here is the `.*`, `.` means any character and `*` means the thing in front of it can be matched 0 or more times.

Since you want thre matched results, you might also want to wrap it in `()`: `(\$\{.*\})`. The parenthesis makes regex remember the stuff inside for later use.
See this stackoverflow on how to get the results back:
[How to match multiple results using std::regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21667295/how-to-match-multiple-results-using-stdregex)

Comment: inner part seems more interesting, and whole match is given anyway (at least in C++).