# regex_token_iterator<> sometimes misses matched substrings

Tags: c++, regex

I used regex_token_iterator<> to get all matched substrings in a line, as suggested in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21667295/how-to-match-multiple-results-using-stdregex).
But the code sometimes misses 2nd matched substrings in lines, and the lines where this miss happens changes at different runs.
Is this a bug of regex_token_iterator<>, or is there something wrong in my code?
The compiler I used is Apple clang version 14.0.0 (clang-1400.0.29.202), and I used -std=c++14 to compile the following code.

I also tried another suggestion in the question above, which is to use while-loop to repeatedly apply regex_search(), and that version of code worked properly. I just want to know why the version with regex_token_iterator<> is not working, whether my usage is wrong or not.

code:

```
#include<regex>
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<fstream>
#include<sstream>

using namespace std;

struct bad_from_string : bad_cast{
  const char* what() const noexcept override{
    return "bad cast from string";
  }
};

template<typename T>
T from_string(const string& s){
  istringstream is{s};
  T t;
  if(!(is>>t))
    throw bad_from_string{};
  return t;
}

int main(){
  regex pat{R"((\d{1,2})/(\d{1,2})/(\d{4}))"}; // e.g. 7/21/2022
  ifstream ifs{"test_regex_token_iterator.txt"};
  ofstream ofs{"test_out_regex_token_iterator.txt"};

  regex_token_iterator<string::iterator> rend; // default constructor is used for indicating the end of the sequence
  
  for(string line; getline(ifs, line);){
    smatch matches;
    
    string replace_pattern; 

    int month{0}, day{0}, year{0};

    regex_token_iterator<string::iterator> riter(line.begin(), line.end(), pat);
      
    // for each matched substring, replace it individually
    while(riter!=rend){
      string matched_substring{(*riter).str()};
      // *riter returns a reference to the sub_match object riter is pointing to.
      // sub_match is not a string. sub_match::str() returns the string of the sub_match.
      
      // put each matched substring into variable "matches"
      regex_search(matched_substring, matches, pat);
      
      // get the day, month, and year values in int
      day = from_string<int>(matches.str(2));
      month = from_string<int>(matches.str(1));
      year = from_string<int>(matches.str(3));
      
      // here make replace_pattern yyyy-mm-dd
      if(month<10 && day<10)
        replace_pattern = to_string(year)+"-0"+to_string(month)+"-0"+to_string(day); // both day and month need the fron '0'
      else if(month<10)
        replace_pattern = to_string(year)+"-0"+to_string(month)+"-"+to_string(day);
      else if(day<10)
        replace_pattern = to_string(year)+"-"+to_string(month)+"-0"+to_string(day);
      else
        replace_pattern = to_string(year)+"-"+to_string(month)+"-"+to_string(day);
      
      line = regex_replace(line, regex(matched_substring), replace_pattern); // regex_replace() returns a string
      // since I want to replace only 1 matched substring *riter, I use the exact substring 
      // in the place of regex pattern
      
      ++riter;      // move to the next matched substring
    }
  
    ofs << line << endl; 
  }
  
  return 0;
}
```

test_regex_token_iterator.txt:

```
12/01/2022 - 12/31/2022
12/01/2022 - 12/31/2022
12/01/2022 - 12/31/2022
12/01/2022 - 12/31/2022

10/01/2022 - 10/31/2022
10/01/2022 - 10/31/2022
10/01/2022 - 10/31/2022
10/01/2022 - 10/31/2022
10/01/2022 - 10/31/2022
```

sample test_out_regex_token_iterator.txt (but the result changes in different runs):

```
2022-12-01 - 12/31/2022
2022-12-01 - 2022-12-31
2022-12-01 - 12/31/2022
2022-12-01 - 12/31/2022

2022-10-01 - 10/31/2022
2022-10-01 - 2022-10-31
2022-10-01 - 10/31/2022
2022-10-01 - 10/31/2022
2022-10-01 - 10/31/2022
```

I expected all the matched substrings, including the dates in the 2nd column, were replaced, but only part of them were replaced properly.
The expected result:

```
2022-12-01 - 2022-12-31
2022-12-01 - 2022-12-31
2022-12-01 - 2022-12-31
2022-12-01 - 2022-12-31

2022-10-01 - 2022-10-31
2022-10-01 - 2022-10-31
2022-10-01 - 2022-10-31
2022-10-01 - 2022-10-31
2022-10-01 - 2022-10-31
```

Comment: `-fsanitize=address` is your friend. It will tell you immediately where the problem is.

Comment: @n.m. Thank you for the useful option. I used it and ran the buggy program before applying the answer, but all I can know is somewhere in the program, heap-use-after-free happened, and other messages are rather cryptic. So after knowing such a problem is happening, the option doesn't tell me at which line of the program the problem was caused, does it? i.e. I have to carefully read the program to find where that error occurred

Comment: It tells you that the line `++riter` causes the problem. Why could incrementing an operator cause a problem? Because the iterator is invalid. Why is it invalid? Etc etc

Comment: Thank you for the follow-up. The problem I had with the output messages was that they specified addresses in the executable binary, not line numbers in the source file. I could solve this by adding -g option when compiling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

enabling address sanitiser shows that your code is causing undefined behaviour: https://godbolt.org/z/n3rnn9nqY

`riter` contains iterators from `line` but at the end of your while loop you reassign `line`, invalidating `line`'s iterators and therefore invalidating `riter`, when you then try to increment `riter` you enter the realms of undefined behaviour.

Adding a separate string for your output fixes the problem: https://godbolt.org/z/Grqe1vv5x

```
for(string line; getline(ifs, line);){
  smatch matches;
  string outputLine = line;
  
  string replace_pattern; 

  int month{0}, day{0}, year{0};

  regex_token_iterator<string::iterator> riter(line.begin(), line.end(), pat);
    
  // for each matched substring, replace it individually
  while(riter!=rend){
    string matched_substring{(*riter).str()};
    // *riter returns a reference to the sub_match object riter is pointing to.
    // sub_match is not a string. sub_match::str() returns the string of the sub_match.
    
    // put each matched substring into variable "matches"
    regex_search(matched_substring, matches, pat);
    
    // get the day, month, and year values in int
    day = from_string<int>(matches.str(2));
    month = from_string<int>(matches.str(1));
    year = from_string<int>(matches.str(3));
    
    // here make replace_pattern yyyy-mm-dd
    if(month<10 && day<10)
      replace_pattern = to_string(year)+"-0"+to_string(month)+"-0"+to_string(day); // both day and month need the fron '0'
    else if(month<10)
      replace_pattern = to_string(year)+"-0"+to_string(month)+"-"+to_string(day);
    else if(day<10)
      replace_pattern = to_string(year)+"-"+to_string(month)+"-0"+to_string(day);
    else
      replace_pattern = to_string(year)+"-"+to_string(month)+"-"+to_string(day);
    
    outputLine = regex_replace(outputLine, regex(matched_substring), replace_pattern); // regex_replace() returns a string
    // since I want to replace only 1 matched substring *riter, I use the exact substring 
    // in the place of regex pattern
    
    ++riter;      // move to the next matched substring
  }

  ofs << outputLine << endl; 
}
```